# Ruby/Rails Model Relationships Across Disparate Services/APIs (SOA)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soa, rails-api

I'm working on building a suite of (micro)services using Ruby/Rails (Grape, Rails-API etc.) which feed user-facing web/mobile applications. These services are self-contained/isolated, however there is a need to have some cross-service relationships between models/entities.

In the case of a `has_one`/`belongs_to` relationship, I can simply store the `ID` of the foreign entity within the local model and vice versa. The problem I'm facing is how to handle a `has_many`/`belongs_to` or `has_many`/`has_many` relationship(s).

For example, if I had an `Order` and `Product` model, in a monolithic Rails app I would do the following:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products, through :order_products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders, through :order_products
end

class OrderProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
    belongs_to :product
end
```

How can this type of a relationship be handled when dealing with disparate services? Is there a 'rails way' to do this?

So far the best option I've come up with is to store the foreign `ID`s as a hash within the model using something like PostgressSQL's `hstore` column, but this feels wrong both from a scalability and data-integrity standpoint.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is disparate about the relationship between Orders and Products?

Are you putting Orders in one service and Products in another?

Comment: I'm curious of this same issue.  In my situation I have a User service and other services that utilize user (think creator id on the separate services).  Another example would be a tagging service or comment service.  I believe an API gateway is the best way for them to communicate with each other.  My question is what is the preferred way to expose these models so that the API gateway can sew them together?

Answer (score 0):

> These services are self-contained/isolated, however there is a need to have some cross-service relationships between models/entities.

the *rails way* (TM) is to have a monolithic application for this kind of relationship.

if you have these kind of constraints and you are building "microservices" - in my opinion, you are not doing a good job architecting your platform.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see how you could do it as in the monolithic app. But, you could easily validate the presence of the foreign id and manage the relationship creation and deletion yourself. Perhaps an example from livingsocial could help you (quite generous of them to share their best Rails SOA practices): 

https://techblog.livingsocial.com/blog/2014/05/06/soa-the-what-the-why-and-the-rules-of-engagement/

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is create a microservice called OrderProduct and have one table that correlates the order_id and the product_id.

Alternatively, you can put Order and OrderProduct in one service and Product in the other service... then when you want an order, just search by product_id and you'll get the orders.

I don't think I need to say it but you can put Product and OrderProduct in one service and Order in the other service.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that Orders and Products are in separate services.

The most difficult part of developing microservices is defining the boundaries. That is, what functionality goes in which microservice. This is surprisingly difficult to do before building the services, and the reason that some people suggest building a monolithic app first and then cutting out the microservices.

One big question to answer is why are Orders and Products in separate services? How did you decide to separate them? Does it make more sense for them to be in the same service?

I think the answer to your question depends on which service is going to access Orders and Products. Does one service need access both?

You could store an array of foreign key ids on one service. This would work if one service only needs to pull data from the other. This is the same thing as "simply storing the ID of the foreign entity within the local model". The only difference is that you would store an array of ID's.

However, there may be use cases that would require storing an array on both services, so that either one would need to know about the has_many relationship on the other. If this is the case then I think that the design is not good. You would have to duplicate the data on both services. This would make it easy for the data to get out of sync.

One possible solution would be to share the database between two services.